# Estructurar pagina html sin tener que usar php

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Estoy desarrollando una pagina solo con el uso de JS tanto en Frontend como en el Backend. No quiero usar php para introducir una parte del codigo html como muestro a continuación:

```
<?php include "estructura/cabecera.html"?>
```

Realmente lo que quiero es hacer una pagina modulada y no tener que estar actualizando cada pagina html cuando tengo que cambiar el Menu, o el Footer o algo.

Comment: Cuando haces <?php include "estructura/cabecera.html"?> se refiere a que estas incluyendo un archivo, puedes incluirlo en infinitos archivos de tu pagina web con un simple include, todo lo que haces en cabecera.html se actualizara en todas las paginas donde estas incluyendo el archivo y no tienes que hacer lo que indicas "estar actualizando cada pagina html cuando tengo que cambiar el Menu, o el Footer o algo." ya que al hacer el cambio en el archivo que estas incluyendo se mostrara en todas las paginas donde el archivo este incluido

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o duda específica? Tal como está planteada tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: Te pregunto, cual es el problema con incrustar los archivos con include de php? para mi es la forma más acertada. Incrustar desde html no está soportado por todos los navegadores, el uso de iframe está desaconsejado, e incrustar por medio de javascript tengo entendido que dicho código es ilegible por los motores de búsqueda, por lo que no es aconsejable por temas de SEO.

Comment: Si estás enemistado con PHP por algún motivo (lo cual siento por ti, no por PHP), [puedes usar `object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/object), que te permitirá incluir un archivo en el cliente.